Undocumented Reserved Types in typescript?
I'm using nuxt / typescript. I believe this a typescript thing, but I can't completely rule out nuxt yet due to its auto importing scheme.
I created a type like so:
export interface Location {
  id: string,
  myVal: string,
}

Upon using this type in another module I found that there seem to be a number of reserved types:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API

I'm a little disturbed to find there seem to be a large number of globally reserved types.  Furthermore I haven't seen docs on this?  Where do these reserved types come from, and how many are there?

• What do you mean by "reserved" here? Just because something is declared doesn't mean it's "reserved"; you are free to shadow it in your own scope. "reserved" usually means that you can't use it yourself at all. Like, you can't make your own variable or type named return because that is reserved. Maybe you just mean "declared"? You can certainly name something Location, just not something in the same scope as something else named Location. Did you import yours? Please [edit] to clarify.

• What do you mean by "documented"? Anything that exists in JavaScript will have corresponding typings in TypeScript, and those JavaScript things are documented all over the place.  For example, Location is documented. Maybe you mean something more specific, like... documented in a particular way on a particular web site? The TS handbook documents the fact that its standard libraries exist, is that not what you mean? Please [edit] to clarify.
